# Response.Redirect vs Server.Transfer - redirect as a "suggestion"

Tags: asp.net

So I read an [article](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=15) on Response.Redirect that say's "its like a suggestion" as compared to Server.Transfer which happens whether the client wants to or not.  What does this mean?  Is there some kind of event that we can offer a user to say "well nope nm I don't want to redirect to that page"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Server.Transfer` will execute the new page immediately and send its result to the client.
The client stays at the original URL doesn't see anything unusual.

`Response.Redirect` sends a special code, called an [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), that tells the client to send a new request to a different URL.

Comment: Why is this practical? I see there's some issues with Context (per the article), but is that really the only thing? I'm def. a pragmatic guy, I need to see some usefulness for Server.Transfer in order to consider it good to use over Redirect for some given scenerio.

Comment: To have two methods that perform the same task

Comment: The two methods are rather different.  `Server.Transfer` can be useful if you want to hide the URL of the new page.

Comment: Also server.transfer will work only for pages hosted within the same server. If you are navigating to a different host then responser.redirect is the only way

Answer (score 3):

### Response.Redirect

`Response.Redirect` will navigate to the url specified.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Any response body content such as displayed HTML text or Response.Write text in the page indicated by the original URL is ignored. However, this method does send other HTTP headers set by this page indicated by the original URL to the client. An automatic response body containing the redirect URL as a link is generated. The Redirect method sends the following explicit header, where URL is the value passed to the method, as shown in the following code:

### Server.Transfer

`Server.Transfer` will execute the url passed in but maintain the url transfered from.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> When you use the Transfer method, the state information for all the built-in objects are included in the transfer. This means that any variables or objects that have been assigned a value in session or application scope are maintained. In addition, all of the current contents for the Request collections are available to the .asp file that is receiving the transfer.

---

Here's [an article](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm) discussing and comparing the two.

Answer (score 1):

It's "like a suggestion" in the sense that when the client requests a url that's redirected, the server responds with "that object has moved...find it here." When you do Server.Transfer, you immediately respond with the output of the page to which you're transferring.

There's nothing in either process you could hook into to give the user any choice...you'd have to respond with a 200 and implement the choice to the user through logic.

Answer (score 1):

Response.Redirect involves a "roundtrip" to the server whereas Server.Transfer conserves server resources by "avoiding the roundtrip". It just changes the focus of the webserver to a different page and transfers the page processing to a different page.